# Universal space for compact spaces that are countable

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Is there compact countable space $X$ s.t. every compact countable space $Y$ is continuous image of $X$?

Comment: Surely not, in fact I doubt you can get every countable successor ordinal...

Comment: Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum.

Comment: I don't understand, why this post has been closed. I think it's quite an intereresting question. Ok, the OP does not provide any context, but it's certainly not one of this kind "please solve exercise ..." I would be keen to know what the answer is. Does the one, who voted for closing, know it?